# My jQuery animation isn't working, even though I see nothing wrong with the jQuery section code

Tags: jquery, html, css

Little background: this is an absolute beginner's website. I am a Film major haha

I included jQuery in Notepad++ as a document and saved in on the desktop with everything else.
The title of the document is jquery-1.7.1.js

As you can probably tell from the code, my goal is for that paragraph to be hidden, and then on click, it will reveal the paragraph through the slideDown method in the jQuery library.
The website seems to recognize the slideDown(5000) but does not seem to know the hide().

Oh, and if anything else is wrong, please tell me. Even if it's just tiny, tiny things. I want to learn the proper conventions early.

https://gist.github.com/1616366

Comment: I can't see any `slideDown(5000)`, only `show(5000)`. But that should work as well. I don't want to go through the whole code and debug it - that's what you should do, actually. Please try to isolate the part that is not working and only post that part here. You shouldn't require the users here to browse through code in an external repository.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please always include the relevant code *in the question itself* rather than (or in addition to) off-site. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: It could have something to do with the fact that, on `p#derp`, you're closing the `p` and `center` tags the wrong way round. You also have a malformed comment tag around the `style.css` part (you open the comment tag before the `style` tag and close it within the `style` tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML, you have to properly nest tags.  With improper nesting, what you think is in a particular object is not necessarily what the browser thinks is in it.  For example, Chrome thinks your `<p id='derp'>` tag is empty.  To fix the nesting, change this:

```
<p id='derp'><center> In this homework assignment, we had to make this website and compare two programs in different language to see the key differences between ActionScript and Java</p></center>
```

to this:

```
<center><p id='derp'> In this homework assignment, we had to make this website and compare two programs in different language to see the key differences between ActionScript and Java</p></center>
```

or even better use CSS to do the centering so there is no tag nesting for center.

When I fix the nesting, your HTML/JS works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Hk3NY/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtKNA/. This should be the answer. I've put the `text-align: center;` into the CSS, reformatted some of the tags (removed the deprecated `center` tags and applied class `center` to anything you want centered. I then changes the `.show(5000)` to `.slideDown(5000)` and it's working find. Horrible having such a deep purple on black though.